# Elastic search : Epoch time date detection in dynamic mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana-5

I have a dynamically mapped index in Elastic Search. One of the fields `lastUpdated` is an epoch time which is being detected as `long`. How do I ensure this is picked up as `date` type. Is there a way to modify one of the fields (type change from long to date) in an existing index ?